# Vuex and mysql connection object: Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I've got an electron application that uses mysql package to connect to my database directly. What I'm trying to do is to store `connection` object created with `mysql.createConnection()` in the Vuex state. Then I want to fetch some numbers from the database using this object.

I got this code for Vuex store:

```
const state = {
  connectionObject: null,
  numbers: [],
};

const getters = {
  getNumbers: state => state.numbers,
  getConnectionObject: state => state.connectionObject,
};

const mutations = {
  SET_NUMBERS(state, numbers) {
    state.numbers = Object.assign({}, numbers);
  },
  SET_CONNECTION_OBJECT(state, connection) {
     state.connectionObject = connection;
  },
};

const actions = {
  fetchNumbers({ state, commit }) {
    const connection = _.cloneDeep(state.connectionObject);
    connection.query({
      sql: 'SELECT * FROM `numbers`',
      timeout: 40000,
    }, async (error, results) => {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      }
      commit('SET_NUMBERS', await results);
    });
  },
  connectToDatabase({ commit }, data) {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.connect(async (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        commit('SET_CONNECTION_OBJECT', await connection);
        commit('SET_DB_CONNECTION_STATE', data);
        return resolve(connection);
      });
    });
  },
};
```

What happens is once I run the code I get `Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."` and this error is thrown when `connection.query()` is executed.

I have a hard to time understand why it doesn't work as I clone `connectionObject` from state after all. Seem like its observers get cloned as well. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection object is highly mutable, it can not be stored. Every connection you make does change properties of the connection object. I would only store the returns in the storage, the data update in to the actions and the connectionobject should be made accessable across vuex, beware making it global though, this would make your app easier to hack. One way to make it accessable is by simply declaring it a variable besides  the state.

If you need further advice it would be greate to know which SQL package you used in order to give you some code.

Comment: But I am still curious why exactly I got this error. As for declaring the `connection` variable besides the state, that's what I've done when I failed to store it in the state. I'm using mysqljs/mysql package btw.

Comment: I think you're confused because you never encountered a edgecase where underscores deepcopy does not work ;) Lets say you make a request to your SQL server and it awnsers you back even if you deep copy the connection object all the other connection objects still recive the awsner, it will use something like a thread Id to identify which object is the evoker of the request and by deepcopying the connection it has the same thread Id as the connection in the state, resulting in a mutation on both. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/lib/Connection.js